# Turn a variable string into a strict object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to be able to create a string as %%variable%% and have it interpreted as a method object rather than a string object. So %%UserDatabase.name%% would be read like @DatabaseUser.name and subsequently return something like, "Michael".

Here's what I have so far:

```
def parse_block(component)
  component.gsub!(/%%([a-z].*)%%/s, "@#{'\\1'}")
end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to interpret it before re-inject it.

```
def parse_block(component)
  component.gsub!(/%%([a-z].*)%%/s) do |c|
    eval($1)
  end
end
```

But It's a really bad idea and you can have some Security issue if you string is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead you could pass a model name, a model id, and the desired method? So you would end up with

```
def parse_whatever(model_name, model_instance_id, method)
  active_record_class = Kernel.const_get(classname)
  active_record_instance = active_record_class.find(model_instance_id)
  active_record_instance.send(method)
end
```